# Is it logically possible to consistently name commits in a VCS using an ordered sequence?

Tags: design, version-control

Imagine you're creating a completely new version control system, like Git, Mercurial, SVN etc. from scratch. Rather than identifying commits by SHA hashes, you identify them using an ordered sequence of numbers and letters, from `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` etc. If you make a branch from a commit, you call that commit `1a`, and then further commits from that are `1b`, `1c`, `1d`... If you branch from `1a`, you get a new commit `1a1`, from which follows `1a2`, `1a3`... If you go past the end of the alphabet, you loop around to `aa`, `ab` etc. like in Excel.

It looks like this:

```
1---2---3---4---5 ... 64---65
\
 1a---1b---1c ... 1z---1aa---1ab
  \
   1a1---1a2---1a3
           \
            1a2a
```

So a summation of the sequence rule would be:

1. The name of every commit is incremented from the name of the parent commit, either by incrementing the number, or incrementing the letter.
2. Only the last number/letter is "incremented" using the rule above
3. A commit name can consist of an alternating string of numbers and letters, where "numbers" can be 1 or more digits, and "letters" can be one or more letters. But you cannot have two strings of numbers, or two strings of letters, in a row.

Now there are two problems I've identified with this, and I'm not sure if there's a solution.

1. Merge commits. E.g. if commit `65` and commit `1ab` merge, what do I name the merge commit? Do I make an arbitrary choice and flip a coin to make the new commit either `66`, or `1ac`? I need to designate one of the parent commits as the "true" parent and increment that name to arrive at the merge commit name. But what logic do I use to conclude which commit is the "true" parent?
2. If you have multiple branches from the same commit, there's currently no logical way to name the next branch from that commit. If I branch from `1` I get `1a`. The next commit after `1a` is `1b`. If I branch *again* from `1`, I therefore can't use `1b`

Problem 1 visualised:

```
1---2---3---4---5... 64---65------???
\                                /
 1a---1b---1c ... 1z---1aa---1ab/
```

And problem 2:

```
1---2---3
|\
| 1a---1b
 \
  ???
```

For problem 1, I originally thought of identifying the "ancestor" commit - i.e. the commit that connects all of the commits you're trying to merge, and then following the branch of that "ancestor" until you get to the parent of the merge commit. But I realised that that's fundamentally flawed, because finding the one commit that connects all of your merge commit parents, doesn't tell you which branch to follow to get back to the merge commit - they're all equally valid branches.

The main solution I've thought for branching (problem 2) would be to introduce a separate signifier for branches and commit numbers, maybe separated by a punctuation character. E.g.

```
1---2---3
|\
| 1a.1---1a.2---1a.3
|\
| 1b.1---1b.2---1b.3
 \
  1c.1---1c.2---1c.3
         |\
         | 1c.2a.1---1c.2a.2
          \
           1c.2b.1---1c.2b.2
```

But that already seems to be ludicrously complex at only a few levels of branching.

So my question is: is there any reasonable and logical approach one could take to name commits using a system like this, or would this system fail from the outset? In particular:

1. Could you name merge commits in a systematic way, without simply choosing which parent commit to "increment" the name of at random?
2. Could you name branch commits in this system without names quickly becoming long and complicated to read?

I'm prepared to accept the answer "No to both, this system is fundamentally flawed", but would like to see if there are possible solutions to this problem that I hadn't envisaged.

Comment: The first question: **why?** What are you actually trying to gain here?

Comment: That's a fair question. I'm interested in sketching out ways that a VCS could be designed in ways that don't require beginners to version control to understand concepts like hashes or SHAs - which some could argue is more complexity than a user may want from a VCS. A different level of abstraction, if you will. This was one idea that I had. I recognise that it's flawed but wanted to put it up here for criticism to see if this idea is salvageable.

Comment: "ways that don't require beginners to version control to understand concepts like hashes or SHAs" – At least in Git, you don't need to understand concepts like hashes or SHAs. You can just treat them as opaque identifiers. You don't even know that they are SHA-1 hashes or even that they are hashes at all, or what a hash is. All you need to know is that each object in Git has a unique name that is based on its content.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Sure, I agree with that. I'm not here to say Git is bad or it's design choices are wrong, but I'm interested in ways that VCS could be done differently, which is the XY problem Flater asked after.

Comment: You could consider the branch with fewer number/alpha/number parts to be the "parent" to be merged into, so 65 would win out over 1ab and the merged branch would be 66. The idea is, "more branched" branches are always merging *into* "less branched" ones.

Comment: @DavidConrad I like that idea! It would be pretty easy to implement - essentially choose the simplest parent to base the merge commit name on.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding having versions tied to branches and focus on CI/CD practices to control your software versioning from the trunk instead.    If you want to reduce complexity and make things easier for beginners, then it doesn't really get much simpler than that because the only time you'd ever create a new version would be after a merge into the trunk/master/main branch;  you won't need to solve all these problems because they won't exist.

Comment: @BenCottrell - When you talk about CI/CD practices, were you thinking of anything in particular? E.g. Caleth's suggestion of controlling commit numbers globally, or did you have a different idea?

Comment: @Lou several things - firstly separation of versioning away from source control,  allowing a CI/build system to "tag" the trunk,  having a workflow which prevents direct commits into the trunk and only accepts merge-commits,   a CI tool which maintains the version number and tags every trunk commit with a new version (Giving you the flexibility to choose your own semantic versioning, for example, a CI server could automatically generate a `YYYY.MM.DD.num` version)....  (/1)

Comment: (/2) Other factors would be keeping development/feature branches themselves short-lived because that avoids nightmare merge conflicts and means that 'branch' versions are generally obsolete really quickly.    You might also consider allowing the CI process to publish the built, versioned artefacts up to a kind of package/image/container registry too so that each version is only ever built exactly once (branches could potentially publish "unstable" artefacts if necessary for testing).  Overall, a big topic, but personally I'm not a fan of allowing source control to drive the version scheme.

Comment: This gets into very hairy distributed computing territory. You might use something like Interval Tree Clocks or at least use them as a basis. Note: I am assuming a distributed version control system. The centralized problem is trivial and boring.

Comment: @JörgWMittag "The centralized problem is trivial and boring" Well, the system I'm imagining doesn't have to be a DVCS. I'm guessing the centralised solution for you is that the single source of truth remote repo names the commits, and local commits just get the names from the remote?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned rebase...

Comment: @Lou: Your entire problem revolves around synchronization. In a centralized system, *there is nothing to synchronize*, so the problem you are presenting simply does not exist in the first place. You mention Subversion in your question. Subversion does have unique revision numbers which are not content-based / hashes, and that is easy to do precisely because Subversion is centralized. Heck, you could just use a timestamp, which is again trivial because you don't have to synchronize clocks – there is only one clock.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The problems *outlined in the question* aren't to do with synchronization, they're purely about modelling the history. There are absolutely *unmentioned* problems with synchronization, although as I mentioned to Hans-Martin Mosner below, most people don't actually make full use of git's decentralization anyway, so an alternative model seems possible.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a different naming scheme for branches if you give up on "sequential" numbers in a branch, and instead go for globally increasing.

```
1---2---5---7---21... 64---65------66
\                                 /
 3---4---6    ...    61---62---63/
```

However this and your scheme only work with a central source of truth for names, so neither will be a DVCS.

Comment: Ah yeah, so this is essentially the same approach as SQL - auto-increment the commit name. I see what you mean about a central source of truth though, and how easily this would clash between local and remote repo

Comment: @Lou You are bringing up memories of [VSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe) and all the 3rd party tools that were developed so you could use VSS in a sort of local/remote type of architecture.

Comment: @Lou: This is exactly what Subversion does. Every commit increases the Revision by 1.

Comment: The main frame challenge here is that this is impossible with a distributed VCS. Unless you intend to throw off-line work modes out, no scheme that requires central coordination can work.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner To frame challenge the frame challenge () off-line doesn't necessarily have to mean fully distributed. In theory, git is fully decentralised, but in practice, most people use a "source of truth" hosted somewhere like Github or Gitlab, and often require all actions on "core" branches to be done directly there, not offline. So a system that allowed you to "claim", say, all branches prefixed with your username, would allow you to build as many branches as you wanted offline, then upload them to the central server. Commit numbers based on branch would then also be possible.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner who said distributed?

Comment: Yeah this is a good frame challenge and counter-frame challenge. As Caleth points out, I'm not necessarily assuming DVCS or fully DVCS here. I'm modelling my design close to Git because that's what I know, but the point is that I'm interested in what assumptions can be changed from the Git model. So centralised commit naming is not a bad idea.

Comment: Subversion (and Perforce) don't have a clash between local and remote repo because *there is only one repo*. The copy you have is called a "checkout", and when you make a commit it's through the server. Another frame challenge is "in a world where almost everyone is online almost all the time, do you really want the cost of fully distributed?"

Answer (score 5):

Your problems mostly arise from an inconsistent set of base assumptions.

On the one hand, you have assumed that "branching" is a different operation than "committing to a branch"; but on the other, you've assumed that "merging into" is indistinguishable from "merging from".

If you take a git-like model of history as a Directed Acyclic Graph, the first assumption is incorrect. *Every* commit "branches off from" its parent, in the sense that any commit can be treated as a branch tip in its own right. So commit `1` would be immediately followed by commit `1a`, then `1a1`, and so on. If you are creating a child of commit `1` but `1a` is already in use, that's commit `1b`. You would quickly get commit identifiers with hundreds of 1's and a's, and as you point out, merge commits have two natural names (or more, if you allow more than two parents, as git does).

If on the other hand you take the view that branches are a core concept, with commits directly "belonging to" a branch, then the second assumption is incorrect. If commit `65` is "on a branch", and you merge commit `1ab` "into that branch", the result is unambiguously commit `66`, because it belongs to the same branch as commit `65`. It wouldn't be commit `1ac`, because that would imply you're continuing the other branch. If you wanted to indicate that it was a merge commit, you could mention its extra source, e.g. `66.1ab`

The problem of multiple branches from one point can be solved by always incrementing a number as you go "along" a branch, and adding a letter only when you "create" a branch: `45d6` is the 6th commit on branch `45d`, which is the 4th branch from commit `45` of the original branch. A commit "continuing" that branch would be `45d7` ("branch 45d, commit 7"); but a commit "branching from" it would be `45d6a1` ("branch 45d6a, commit 1"). In this scheme, branch identifiers always end in letters, and commits in numbers. Eventually, you would end up with things like `213c42g17` and `213c42g65a25`, which you can see at a glance share a common parent branch `213c42g`; whereas `213c42f21` is from a different branch (`213c42f`) with common ancestor `213c42`.

Another assumption that could be challenged is that commits always have the same identifier. In Mercurial, commits have a local shorthand which is incremental within a particular list. It is possible (and indeed common) to draw some subset of a git repository as though it was a linear "current branch" with "other branches" splitting from and joining to it. Pick a starting point, and you could label each commit in such a subset with a systematic identifier; you just need some other way to identify that frame of reference.

Ultimately, the format of commit identifiers has to go hand in hand with some definition of what a commit actually is, and that definition varies a lot between the many versioning systems that have been invented over the decades.

Comment: Thanks, this contains a series of good assumption challenges. I see what you mean about viewing each commit as being a branch tip in its own right. The only thing I don't get is how your suggested naming scheme differs from mine. I'm assuming you mean that from commit `45` we have four branches, `45a1`, `45b1`, `45c1` and `45d1`. Then as I create commits on branch `45d1` I eventually get to `45d6`. If I were to branch again from `45` I'd have `45e1`. But then if I were to branch from `45d1`, wouldn't that also be `45e1`? Or are you proposing to then add a new letter `45d1a1`?

Comment: @Lou Yes, I'm saying that if you can tell the difference between "commit to existing branch" and "create new branch", then "commit to existing branch on top of `45d1`" could be `45d2`, and "create new branch from `45d1`" could be `45d1a1`. They could be read as "branch 45d, commit 2" and "branch 45d1a, commit 1" - branches end in letters, commits in numbers. Eventually, you would end up with things like `213c42g17` and `213c42g65a25`, which you can see at a glance share a common parent branch `213c42g`; whereas `213c42f21` is from a different branch (`213c42f`) with common ancestor `213c42`.

Comment: Ah nice! Yes that makes sense and seems logical and consistent, thanks :). I'm seeing now that at advanced levels of branching it would outweigh the complexity of an abbreviated SHA hash, but perhaps that would encourage regular merges/rebases. Perhaps it's easier to understand than a hash ID is if you've never heard of a hash though